# What is the condition for the equation: $ca^2 - (c+1)ab + b^2$ to be non-negative?

Tags: number-theory

Can this be generalized for anything other than the trivial case of $c=1$? When $c=1$, the equation reduces to $a^2 - 2ab + b^2$ which is $(a-b)^2$ and non-negative.

What happens for other positive values of c (c can never be negative in my equation), assuming a and b are non-negative quantities?

I guess, what I really want to prove is that the quantity $(ca - b)(a-b)$ will never be negative.

Comment: Just think about $b=ca$ and $b=a$ as lines in the $(a,b)$-plane, one with varying coefficient. For the product to be negative either one of the two terms must be negative the other positive ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the graph of $y=(x-ca)(x-a)$ is a parabola which crosses the axis $y=0$ at $x=a$ and $x=ca$ so the expression is negative if $x$ lies strictly between $a$ and $ca$

Comment: This works! Many thanks!